# Есть ли случаи, когда C лучше C++?

Tags: c, c++

Здравствуйте. Вопрос из заголовка переписывать не буду.

Интересуют реальные примеры, т.е. не те, когда компилятора C++ под *какую-то* платформу нет. Различия, в несколько процентов, в производительности, несущественны.

Навеяно "мини-наездом" на C++ на [Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/111403/)

**UPD:** Кроме варианта, что C знаем лучше.

Comment: есть, когда вы не владеете с++ :) имхо все зависит от предпочтений человека.

Comment: @vv2cc этот случай чуток не в тему, будем считать, что мы владеем и C++ и C

Comment: Обычно пишут "на чистом си" те, кто не понимает приципы ООП и/или не может их применить в С++.

Comment: У автора статьи на Хабре просто какая-то боль чуть ниже спины. Нет смысла обращаться внимание. Все его посылы там являются лишь субъективным восприятием реальности и ксенофобскими настроениями в области IT.

Comment: Или считает, что принципы ООП для данной задачи не нужны (или их поддержка (реализация) языком не нужна).

Comment: > Обычно пишут "на чистом си" те, кто не понимает приципы ООП и/или не может их применить в С++.

Откуда инфа? Jamie Zawinski, Rob Pike, Ken Tompson, Denis Richie, Linus Torvalds смотрят на тебя с недоумением.

Просто фичи (вроде "ООП", шаблонов, перегружаемых операторов) всегда несут не только пользу но и разрушительную мощь, которая в неумелых руках ломает всё. Мы живём в реальном мире, поэтому это недостаток C++.

Comment: В ответах какие-то ад и погибель. Срань господня, «несовместимо с <s>ООП</s> кислинкой», «яблоки всегда лучше», «истинный ценитель яблок никогда не будет хвалить бананы» совсем, beep, поехали.

Извините, но реально бред в половине ответов.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В общем, реально надо отдавать предпочтение Си тогда, когда стоит очень сильный вопрос оптимизации по времени исполнения и объему памяти. В большинстве случаев это ядра ОС, драйвера (хотя для обоих случаев есть прецеденты написания на С++), базовые утилиты систем, программы для встроенных систем. Возможно, ключевые узлы сетевых распределенных программ с высокой нагрузкой. Ну или как дань традиции - разные утилиты для никсов, которые писать на С++ считается дурным тоном.

Если говорить теоретически, то С имеет одно огромное преимущество перед С++ - простота языка и, как следствие, простота в изучении. С++ сложнее учить, но если его знаешь хорошо, то писать на нем на порядок проще, особенно большие сложные проекты (да и маленькие тоже).

Comment: Вопрос оптимизации ставится тогда, когда код уже написан и оттестирован. То, о чем ты пишешь, называется преждевременной оптимизацией и приводит к серьезным проблемам.
Что касается простоты, то ассемблер еще проще. Простота и скорость разработки - это разные вещи.

Comment: Голубчик, то ли чего-то не понял, то ли я плохо выразился. Если мне, положим, нужно перемалывать несколько миллионов чисел в нескольких тысячах циклах, то я точно возьму не питон и не руби, а С или С++ или фортран, да еще распараллелю, да еще на GPU. Тут то же самое. Базовые элементы системы, то же ядро, требуют максимальной производительности и минимального потребления памяти. Соответственно этому выбирается язык и среда разработки. А потом еще и в процессе написания оптимизация - одно из основных направлений разработки. Это тебе на бухгалтерскую программу писать. Это ядро ОС или драйвер.

Comment: Проще говоря, каждой задаче  - свой инструмент.

Answer (score 9):

Всем привет, расскажу почему я считаю что Си лучше C++. И почему надмножество над другим языком это не всегда хорошо.

[image: C++ FQA]

[больше драмы](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/)

Язык программирования всегда имеет набор фич. Замечено, что чем меньше фич и чем больше соблюдается ортогональность, тем гибче и выразительнее сам язык, тем легче понимать код.

Возьмём к примеру Си: **функции, структуры, указатели, макросы**.
По-большому счёту это всё, примитивные типы можно считать примером структуры из одного элемента. Довольно быстро привыкаешь и понимаешь как каждая из этих фич взаимодействует между собой:

- **функции, указатели**: указатели на функции, функция принимающая указатели
- **функции, структуры, указатели**: структуры содержащие указатели на функции

Макросы никак не взаимодействуют с другими, это просто препроцессор, поэтому тут всё понятно.

И так, можно довольно быстро начать понимать код на Си, т.к. в нём используется ограниченный набор ортогональных фич, хорошо взаимодействующих между собой.

Теперь рассмотрим C++: **функции, структуры, указатели, макросы, классы, шаблоны, ссылки, исключения, операторы, методы**.

Где есть неортогональные пары, которые очень похожи, частично дублируют своё назначение, из-за этого иногда может быть непонятно где какую из двух использовать, код где сталкиваются две фичи может выглядеть криво или быть труднопонятным:

- *указатели и ссылки*
- *структуры и классы*
- *макросы и шаблоны*
- *функции и методы*

Количество фич возросло, да ещё и половина из них неортогональна. Из-за этого программисту приходится делать выбор там, где в других языках за него выбрали проектировщики языка. C++ на порядок более сложный язык.

Может быть кто-то скажет: "Ну и фиг что сложный! Я умный, я осилю, я смогу управлять этой мощью!", может и действительно осилит. Я бы избегал любых лишних мысленных телодвижений.

Си легче понимать и это серьёзное преимущество, в реальной жизни время и силы ограничены, если конечно их не тратить на троллинг на форумах, прихлебывая мамкин борщ.

Comment: Мне очень понравилось.

Comment: В отличие от обычной кошки, инкрементированная умеет летать.

Comment: У yosefk кое-где проскакивает предвзятость. Оно не отменяет кучи бед крестов, но все же. Вот даже тут есть немного неправды.

Функции и методы не сталкиваются. Отличие метода от функции (для крестов) — поддержка виртуализации (суть, наследования) и неявная передача `this`. Иметь шорткаты, это, как бы, совершенно нормально.

Comment: Ты прав насчет лишних телодвижений. Именно из-за этого я пишу на С++.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то благодаря ООП и шаблонам(это доп. ноги) серьёзно повышается лёгкость повторного использования кода.

Comment: че? Не въехал: в чем разница между методом и функцией? Уж не в том ли, что функция - это свободная ф-ция, а метод - ф-ция-член класса?

Comment: @gecube: я же написал — в двух вещах. Первое — в том, что если `foo` — виртуальный метод, то будет применяться поздное связывание и вызов будет отдиспетчен уже в рантайме, что как бы позволяет (не считая того, что в крестах с ABI все плохо) сувать любые производные объекты. Сделали свой `class Bar : public Foo`, переопределили в нем `virtual baz() ...`, и можно пользоваться. Второе — в том, что методу в `this` будет автоматически/неявно передана инстнанция, которой он принадлежит.

Comment: @drdaeman, Вы напрямую на вопрос не ответили, уехав в дебри реализации.

Comment: @Алексей Лобанов: все хорошее — оно не в количестве конечностей, а в правильных местах их прикрепления к телу.

Повторное использование кода обеспечивается не ООП и шаблонами, а грамотным проектированием.

Comment: Я с ООП-то не шибко знаком, но знающие люди утверждают, что с повторным использованием кода там совсем труба -- для каждого проекта иерархию объектов приходится строить заново. Шаблоны -- ну был юмористический пример, в ктором были одновременно использованы три или четыре шаблона -- зрелище ужасающее (и знатоки, опять же, утверждают, что иначе и быть не должно)

Comment: @gecube, ну если совсем просто, то, да, в том. Методы это такой сахар над функциями, плюс диспетчер сбоку (для виртуальных методов).

Answer (score 8):

Например, если Вы знаете Си лучше (не нужно говорить, что Си подмножество С++ и любая валидная программа на Си будет валидной на плюсах - это два, хотя и похожих, но разных языка программирования).

Либо если Вы - Линус Тордвальдс:) Он дал исчерпывающий [ответ](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/57918).

А пост на хабре от человека, не осилившего плюсы. Настоящий ценитель С никогда не будет хвалить java и С#.

Comment: "любая валидная программа на Си будет валидной на плюсах" --  не совсем так, совместимость не до конца полная, т.к., кажется, в C есть объявление перемнной с типом int по умолчанию, что в C++ вырезали.

Плюсану за Линуса :), правда его ответ не особенно аргументируется :).

Comment: прочитайте, что я писал. Я не утверждал, что си подмножество плюсов.

Comment: Сорри, я видимо не так понял, я думал, что "не нужно говорить" означает очевидность :)

Comment: @KoVadim: Не могу согласиться с вашим последним абзацем. Я ценю С как прекрасный _низкоуровневый_ язык с простой и понятной моделью операций, и замечательной близостью к ассемблеру без присущих ему недостатков. Вместе в тем я ценю и C# как замечательный современный _высокоуровневый_ язык с логичной объектной моделью, прекрасной скоростью развития и защищённостью от глупых ошибок.

Comment: всему своя задача. В большинстве случаев у С и С# совершенно разные задачи. И мало людей смогут и там и там одновременно продуктивно работать. А баловаться в нескольких языках сразу... это все могут.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, Линус сильно написал. Раньше не читал такого его высказывания. Спасибо.

@Алексей Лобанов, с учетом всех ограничений на сравнение  Си и С++, сделанных Вами в вопросе, ответ однозначный - **нет. Си не лучше С++**. 

Поясню, всегда можно написать программу для С++ компилятора фактически на Си, но например, использовать cout<< вместо printf() и т.п.

В случае *небольшой, автономной* программы меня, в отличие от Линуса, от этого передергивать не будет.

Comment: Меня очень порадовало высказывание Линуса
>In other words, the only way to do good, efficient, and system-level and 
portable C++ ends up to limit yourself to all the things that are 
basically available in C.

Так я не понял: system-level или все-таки portable? Одна из прелестей того обкакиваемого им буста (и вообще тенденции развития С++) в том, что system-level  становится portable. Си до этого еще далеко.

Comment: @mikillskegg, видимо я не очень владею английским, я высказывание Линуса в целом понял так, что он сильно сомневается в эффективности и безошибочности реализаций и stl и boost на разных платформах.

Comment: Дело даже не в этом. Я не представляю, как можно совместить в рамках сегодняшних реализаций переносимость и системный уровень в Си. В новом стандарте Си шаг к этому сделан. Но даже gcc пока не торопится с поддержкой С11.

Comment: @mikillskegg: по идее, правильные абстракции + вынос системно-зависимых кусков в условно-компилируемый код + правильный makefile.

Comment: @mikillskegg, а что нового в С11 (в 2-х словах) и насколько оно нужно?

Из (уже далеко не последних) расширений я пользуюсь, пожалуй, только
`typeof`, блоками в выражении `({...}) для \#define, массивами вида `a[n]` (n - переменная) и определением переменных в произвольном месте кода. 

Да, еще, недавно узнал о вложенных функциях, возможно буду использовать.

Comment: @avp, например, <thread>

Comment: @mikillskegg, не понял. 

Потоки (thread) **в Си на уровне языка???** (не библиотека?). Или только примитивы синхронизации (atomic_t для spinlock и т.п. - т.е. *не мьютексы*) и барьеры для машинных инструкций?

Comment: @avp, в новом стандарте С11 введена библиотека thread.h. Но, насколько мне известно, она еще нигде не реализована (хотя могу ошибаться). А вот в С++11 все намного радостней. Плюс еще разные сторонние библиотеки, делающие многие аспекты системного программирования переносимыми. Ясно, что там все внутри построено на #define, но мне уже это писать ручками не нужно.

Comment: "Настоящий ценитель С никогда не будет хвалить java и С#." — а на sezn.ru есть форум про религии? Потому что если у кого-то такой мусор в голове, и он не может нормально пользоваться языками — это не на Хэшкод, это туда.

Answer (score 3):

Распространенное заблуждение.

`Си++` сделан для того, чтобы дополнять `Си`, но ни как не противостоять. А умники, которые пытаются "зачморить" что-то одно - ущербны: либо просто не знают всей кухни программирования (в том числе `C/C++`), либо сталкивались с ситуациями, когда использоваание повсеместно первого логически превращало реализацию проекта в утопию (или очень сильно усложняло жизнь).

Моя правда - это **грамотное проектирование**, на этапе которого выясняются все нюансы **реализации** алгоритма, которые и закладывают направление развития проекта. И это развитие может быть и в сторону `Си` и в второну `Си++` равноправно, в зависимости от нужд программиста в конкретной точке проектирования. Неверно зацикливаться на чем-то одном.

Comment: Судя по минусу и комментарию к вопросу, @Flammable каким-то образом против **проектирования**. Т.к. комментарий ответу не противоречит, интересно было бы знать, его правду :)

Comment: Полностью согласен. 

Если в результате проектирования  прикладной системы возникают взаимодействующие объекты (как сущности моделируемой системы) со своим жизненным циклом, то стоит смотреть на С++, если же проектируется "конвейер" обработки потока данных, то продукт на Си может окакзаться проще.

--

К сожалению TC отмел аргумент
 
     C знаем лучше.

а на мой взгляд это очень важно в реальной разработке.

Answer (score 1):

Лично я бы сказал, что это программирование микроконтроллеров, т.к. ну по-любому можем обойтись тем, что предлагает Си, да и по хорошему говоря, мы не можем или не захотим обойтись без того что он предлагает. Потому что сравнивая что лучше, корректным будет сравнивать подходы которые и отличают С++ от Си. Всегда ли ООП лучше СП(структурного программирования)? Есть ли ситуации когда СП гораздо более желательно чем ООП? Вообще, у трупа страуса, простите, страуструпа, в книге написано, что для решения определенного рода задач, гораздо ценнее тот инструмент, который напрямую предназначен для их решения, т.е. чтобы разделать свинью, разделочный тесак всегда будет лучше швейцарского мультитула (в книге фразы другие, но смысл тот же). Другими словами: процедурное программирование и тесная работа с аппаратурой.

Answer (score 1):

Простите, а можно ещё список случаев, когда использование С++ более оправдано, чем использование С, кроме случаев написания огромных приложений для упрощения понимания и повторного использования, и написания маленьких по тексту, но не очевидных и громадных по исполняемому коду программ авторами, которые боятся что в любом месте их ***-пойми как написанного кода может вылезть выход за пределы массива или приведение указателя на структуру к формату с плавающей запятой и, следственно, ошибка приведения типов?

Comment: Например когда хочется писать программу в стиле ООП. На уровне взаимодействия объектов. И подскажите, в Си все еще пользуются strcpy()?

Comment: А что значит "хочется"? Есть оптимальные решения, их и надо использовать, не зависимо от того, чего вам "хочется".
strcpy пользуют только те, кто любит писать маленькие простенькие программы на С++ не понимая работы компьютера и в данном конкретном случае был вынужден писать на Си.

Comment: @Pavlus: это тянет на отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @VladD,я считаю, это всё тот-же вопрос. Вопрос о разделении областей Си и Си++.

Comment: @Pavlus: "Есть ли случаи, когда C лучше C++". Ы?

Comment: @VladD, а где написано, что С++ лучше С вообще? Это такая негласная истина? Чем он лучше? Не стоит читать вопросы буквально, вы не компьютер, я полагаю.

Comment: @Pavlus: я лично не считаю, что C++ лучше C, но мне кажется, что ТС достаточно чётко выразил суть вопроса. И правда, что вам мешает открыть новый вопрос? Могу поспорить, он будет популярен.

Comment: @VladD, хоть я и чувствую, что разбираюсь в вопросе немного лучше ТС, но не считаю, что смогу сформулировать вопрос намного лучше, чтобы соответствовать своему внутреннему перфекционизму. Потому не буду, та и не интересно мне. Просто колет в одном месте из-за того, что С++ считают как универсальный язык для всего и вся, часто, не писав ничего сложнее чем школьное/олимпиадное задание, где надо просто скопировать из интернета^W^W^W реализовать алгоритм.

Comment: @mikelsv Насчёт использования strcpy -- да. С оговоркой -- в сетевых приложениях все strcpy/strcat/и т.п. вычищены как класс. Но тут ничего не попишешь -- hostile environment. А вот "хочется писать программу в стиле ООП" -- это внушает. "Религия -- рулез" (c) не-помню-чей.

Comment: @Pavlus я не считаю C++ панацеей. На C++ можно написать почти всё, что угодно, некоторые штуки действительно проблемно на нём пишутся. Я так понимаю, это тонкий намёк на меня: "сложнее чем школьное/олимпиадное задание"? Не поверите, я писал кое-что и посложнее, как раз на C++

Answer (score 0):

Сложно сказать.
Может быть, в тех случаях, когда нужно более высокая производительность - но Вы сказали что этот фактор не важен (хотя затраты на абстракцию в Си++ минимальны, в сравнение с такими языками как Пайтон, Руби, и т.д).  
Как второй фактор может быть простота (и скорость) изучения, у Си она значительно выше чем у С++.  
Ну и задачи, решаемые, конечно могу быть разные. 
Вполне может быть такая ситуация что возможности С++ и не нужны, тогда да, имеет смысл сказать, что в таком проекте использовать Си будет "*лучше*", нежели  С++.

Comment: Наверное, сравнивать C++ с Python как-то нехорошо. Они предназначены немножко для разных целей.

Answer (score 0):

С++ (как и вообще ООП) инструмент для написания больших проектов. Напомню, что цель ООП в первую очередь это повышение reusability кода и защиты кода от различных необдуманных модификаций.

Исходя из этого, также из практики, если код небольшой (скажем дне нескольких тысяч строк) - то разумнее использовать обычный Си. Ну или как вариант, если не планируется повторное использование кода в другом приложении.

Comment: ядро линуск это маленький проект?:))))

Comment: C++ это не только ООП, но ещё и шаблоны. И Boost. Я уверен, что если и есть аналоги всему Boost'у в C, то не настолько лаконичные(не простые, нет).

Comment: > ядро линуск это маленький проект?:))))


а код ядра линукса "reusability" ??

Comment: например ядро андроида, многие мультимедийные приставки. Берут код ядра, выпиливают лишнее, добавляют свой функционал и делают свой продукт. А вот ядро видны точно не "reusability".

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat часть - да

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, да Линукс сейчас везде. От будильников до кластеров из TOP10, включая сетевое оборудование.

Comment: @Алексей Лобанов, естественно Си значительно хуже, чем С++ подходит для обобщенного программирования.

На мой взгляд (но это наверное из серии "Си знаем лучше") в большой *чужой* программе на С++ трудно разобраться. Труднее, чем в аналогичной (по функциональности) программе на Си. 

И вот тут, создавая новую систему, надо 7 раз подумать, найдете ли Вы людей, которые смогут ее сопровождать (и за какие деньги специалист, способный на это, возмется за сопровождение).

Comment: @kovadim ядро линуха написано небезызвестным Линусом ярым противником С++, так что мимо. К тому же reusability ядра это фточку :) К тому же ядро начинали писать в пору когда С++ не было и в помине как промышленный продукт

Comment: Насчет маленьких проектов - это как сказать. Используя С++ и STL даже для маленьких программ можно объем кода (и время для его написания) уменьшить в несколько раз по сравнению с С.

Comment: @mikillskegg, не поверите, тоже самое хотел написать :)

Comment: @mikillskegg не отрицаю, что есть такое, но все же достаточно почитать Страуструпа зачем он собственно создал С++ и все станет на свои места. К тому же ваш пример с STL как раз и опирается на reusability :)

Comment: @avp 

> да Линукс сейчас везде. От будильников
> до кластеров из TOP10, включая сетевое
> оборудование.

он везде не потому что он reusability а потому что он открыт, и программисту будильника проще скатать чем мастерить велосипед... (собственно у винды диаметрально противоположная проблема)

так что мимо...

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat: ну отлично, то, что его _смогли_ использовать для всех этих целей уже означает, что с reusability у линукса всё в порядке.

Comment: А что, в C проблемы с ООП какие-то? Синтаксис не предусмотрен — и все?

Answer (score 0):

Есть только один единственный случай, когда Си подходит больше C++ - когда последний недоступен. Во всем остальном C++ лучше.

И я даже не особо понимаю тех людей, которые говорят, что Си не переноситмя в С++. Там максимум нужно немного поработать руками и поправить приведение указателей. И возможно поработать с типами.

Если я попробую переписать свою программу на Си, то скорее повешусь. И мне придется сделать кучу проверок выхода за границу памяти. И, что самое интересное, скорее всего я выделю больше памяти. А про красоту и читаемость кода я вообще молчу.

Comment: @mikelsv, говоря о проверках границ памяти (которые, как следует из Вашего ответа в С++ проверять не надо) Вы имели в виду динамические структуры типа vector и string?

А по поводу красоты и читаемости кода на Си и С++, так по моему они совершенно одинаковы и зависят не от языка, а от писателя. От того, как он может выражать свои мысли на данном языке.

Для примера посмотрите на сишный код Emacs-a. Мне когда-то очень понравился.

Comment: В С++ проверка границ засовывается к класс и больше никак меня не касается. Я имел ввиду любой класс
Про красоту и читаемость это я скорее про объем и излишнюю писанину.

Comment: @mikelsv, 

     В С++ проверка границ засовывается к класс и больше никак меня не касается

Сильное утверждение. 

Выход за границу это очевидная ошибка или в исходных данных или в алгоритме их обработки. 

Так кто, где и как должен на нее реагировать, если Вас, как автора программы это не касается?

Comment: Скорее всего, тут имелось ввиду что-то вроде автоматической проверки на выход за пределы границ контейнера. Только вот плюс это или минус - довольно спорно. Если алгоритм подразумевает возможность такого выхода, который нужно контролировать - это наверняка грубейшая логическая ошибка, которую в плюсах сделать гораздо проще, т.к. такие "автоматические" инструменты позволяют быстро разрешать локальные проблемы, вот только такие инструменты не заставляют разработчика задумываться, что проблема на самом деле **просто закопана, а не решена**.

Comment: @avp, сильно зависит от того, где эта ошибка может всплыть. Вообще, если писать алгоритм - там такой ситуации быть не должно априори (иначе алгоритм корявый). А если это библиотека, которую пользователь (программист) может пытаться использовать и в хвост, и в гриву? Так что все-таки какие-то проверки входных аргументов должны быть. Не вижу проблемы проверить и то, что индекс находится в пределах границ.